# Oracle Sql Automation on houraly basis

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Is there any way i can automate my oracle sql query as i want to get upto date output after every hour, thanks for help

thanks

Comment: Where do you want to see the result set?  Depending on the display this requirement could point to a client-side poller , a middle-tier daemon or a database job.

Answer (score 2):

You can run an Oracle job with [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm) and log the output to a table or a flat file on the server where the database is located.  With a little more work using Oracle built in packages you could have the results [emailed to you](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Send_mail_from_PL/SQL#Send_mail_with_UTL_MAIL).

Here is an example that calls a procedure every five minutes

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(job_name        => v_jobnam,
                          job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
                          JOB_ACTION      => 'BEGIN My_schema.MyProcedure; END;',
                          start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
                          repeat_interval =>  'freq=MINUTELY;interval=5',
                          end_date        => NULL,
                          enabled         => TRUE,
                          comments        => 'Calls PLSQL every five minutes');
```